# Filename completion in gvim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

for some reason, my filename completion in gvim is not working.
In vim, its working properly. Commands and such are, however, completed correctly.
I have set `wildmode=full`.

An example:
Assume i want to open the file `main.c`
I type `:op<Tab>` and gvim gives me a list with all possible completions (open and options). I choose open and continue to `:open m<Tab>`. I would expect gvim to now complete my file, what happens however, is this: `:open m^I`, no completion.

As mentioned, in vim it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I've never used open; I always use `:e(dit)` or `:b(uffer)` (both of which do tab completion correctly), but I get the same behaviour as you describe for gvim with both gvim and vim (`:open` + tab does not complete anything even with absolute paths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean

```
:edit index<tab>
```

Which completes to index.php etc

from Vim Help

```
:help open
```

Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For those
situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex mode, which
allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole screen instead of
only one line.